# cant connect node docker container to mongo docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker, networking

I get this error:

```
Server running...
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongo mongo:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:562:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:316:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:245:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  message:
   'failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongo mongo:27017]',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: docker-node-mongo
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3001:3000'
```

this is how i tried to connet from node script:

```
mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test2',
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log("errorErrorError"));
```

this is the output of docker container ls -a

```
6f14a98e2d51        dockernodemongo_app       "npm start"              11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes           0.0.0.0:3001->3000/tcp                     docker-node-mongo
f3fb55dad886        mongo                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   24 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes           127.0.0.1:27017->27017/tcp                 mongo
```

this is how i run mongo from a another docker-compose.yml file:

```
    mongo:
        restart: always
        image: mongo
        container_name: mongo
        network_mode: "bridge"
#        expose:
#           - 27017
        volumes:
            - ./mongo_data:/data/db
        ports:
            - "127.0.0.1:27017:27017"
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot connect your application to mongo that way. `127.0.0.1` refers to the localhost of the container, not the host. You have two options:

- Create a [network](https://docs.docker.com/network/) and add both containers to it. Then use `mongodb://mongo:27017/test2` to reach the mongo container. Docker will use the service name as a host so you can reach it by that name.
- Bind mongo to 0.0.0.0 (omit the 127.0.0.1 from the port declaration) and connect to the database using the bridge ip address.

Consider the first option, because the second one will expose your mongo database to the internet if you don't have a firewall in place.

For example:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  app:
    container_name: docker-node-mongo
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3001:3000'
    networks:
      - mongo

networks:
  mongo:
    external: true
```

Then on your mongo compose file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  mongo:
    restart: always
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    expose:
      - 27017
    volumes:
      - ./mongo_data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:27017:27017"
    networks:
      - mongo

networks:
  mongo:
    name: mongo
```

Then on your code:

```
mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodb://mongo:27017/test2',
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log("errorErrorError"));
```

edit: updated network names

Comment: problem is that i have sharelatex running which needs mongo and i want to run node which needs mongo, too. So you will recommend to run 2 instances of mongo?

Comment: @KTWorks, why is is a problem? you can both publish a port on the host and create a network so other containers can connect to the service.

Comment: ok. you said this is security problem to publish the port on the host? What do you mean with "you can both publish a port on the host" ? 2 mongo instances?

Comment: I mean that using 27017:27017 will bind to 0.0.0.0 on the host and anybody can connect to mongo from the internet if you don't have a configured firewall, this is why i don't recommend going that route. I will update my andwer with a more complete example.

Comment: thank you i will try it later :) If it works I will accept your answer...

Comment: get error " Additional properties are not allowed ('name', 'attachable' were unexpected)"

Comment: i am using docker compose v2

Comment: @KTWorks your docker version is older than mine (requires 3.5 on the version), you can remove the name and attachable attributes from the files then. You can create the network by hand and reference them in both compose files. Cannot update my answer with the changes right now..

Comment: what do you mean by hand? Own docker compose file?

Comment: tring to do it with v3.5 but now i get networks.mongo value Additional properties are not allowed ('name' was unexpected)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183593/discussion-between-codestation-and-kt-works).